# How can I reset my program to today(Java)

Tags: java, date, reset

I made a program with Java(Eclipse). This program gets the expected date how far from today. I did not shutdown this program(yesterday), this program is using `yesterday's date` instead of today's when I click the button.

Is there a way to recognize it as today without turning the program on and off?

```
private void dispose() {
    new SimpleCalendarOPD();
    calendar.setTime(today);
    ....

    JButton btnReset = new JButton("Reset");
    btnReset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            txtDisplay.setText(null);
            txtDate.setText(null);
            dispose();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the `today` variable from?

Comment: today = LocalDate.now();?

Comment: If your variable still have old values in memory it will work as it is working.

Comment: and hint: better not use dispose as a methodname for something that does initialization. This is kind of signalword for many - like "new" or the like.

Comment: `new Date()` or `LocalDate.now()` *(whichever you're using)* are fast, there is no need to store the value in a *field* named `today`, where it grows stale. Get rid of the field. Use a newly assigned local variable, if you need the value multiple times in a method.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate`  from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For us to understand why your program is behaving the way it is please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Asking a good Stack Overflow question requires some effort. Your effort will often be rewarded. [I downvoted because lacking an MCVE makes it hard to answer](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/).

Comment: @Son50 If we helped solve your problem, then please up-vote the solutions. Also, please consider selecting one as the accepted solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are not updating appropriately. I suggest you use `java.time.LocalTime.now()` every time that *Reset* is clicked.

```
btnReset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        txtDisplay.setText(null);
        txtDate.setText(null);
        // this is an example. Use appropriately in your code
        setTime(java.time.LocalTime.now());
    }});
```

Even if you are getting the time correctly (**which we do not know, because you don't show us**), it means you are not adding it to your display. My other suggestion, is to print the time to the console, so you can pinpoint the bug in your code.

```
private void dispose() {
    new SimpleCalendarOPD();
    calendar.setTime(today);
    //If time is correct, you know that you update the display wrong.
    System.out.println(today);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Question is not clear. Maybe you just want the current date.

## Current date

If you are asking for the current date, call `LocalDate.now`. Pass the time zone through which you want to view the date. Remember that for any given moment the date varies around the globe. It might be tomorrow in Japan while still yesterday in Canada.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

When later you want to know the current date, call `LocalDate.now` again to get another fresh `LocalDate` object. Do not look to the previous `LocalDate` as it is immutable, unchanging, and is not kept up-to-date.

If you want to know if the current moment is the same day or the next day, compare.

```
boolean isNewDay = previousLocalDate.isBefore( LocalDate.now( z ) ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).